# .bashrc giving error after settin $JAVA_HOME PATH

Tags: java, bash, ubuntu

I am getting the following error after setting JAVA_HOME path in bashrc:

bash: export: `=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/usr/lib/java/jdk1.8.0_91/bin': not a valid identifier

bashrc file:

```
#JAVA HOME directory setup
export JAVA_HOME="/usr/lib/java/jdk1.8.0_91"
export PATH =$PATH:$JAVA_HOME/bin
```

When I do echo_$JAVA_HOME, I get the correct path as:
/usr/lib/java/jdk1.8.0_91

When I execute the command **which java**, I get the result as:
/usr/bin/java

What can be the possible solution to solve this problem?

Comment: Use `update-java-alternatives` to set the correct JRE/JDK, and remove your bashrc changes.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In shell while setting a variable there should be no space between the valirable name and `=` character. Just change

```
export PATH =$PATH:$JAVA_HOME/bin
```

to

```
export PATH=$PATH:$JAVA_HOME/bin
```

Comment: Thanks, that worked.

Answer (score 0):

Make JAVA_HOME at the *front* of your path. Otherwise /usr/bin/java will come before /usr/lib/java in the path search.  And lose that leading space as shanmuga points out.

```
PATH=$JAVA_HOME/bin:$PATH
```